# angular, getting query parameter in onNgInit method

Tags: angular

I'm trying to get query parameters inside my component, to use the value to diable or anable the form fields. Unfortunately the parameter is null.

I'm calling the following URL: 'localhost:4200/?myParam=someValue'

When I use the static way

```
    this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('myParam'),
```

the result is always 'null'

When I use the observable

```
 this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {this.param = params.myParam;})
```

and I set a breakpoint to this line, I see that this is calling twice. And the sencond call happens after ngOnInit, so im my method is the value of my param still 'null' yet. How should I get my parameters? Is there maybe a better way to set the attibutes of form fields?
Any suggestions?
Here the code:

```js
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.editMode = EditMode.NEW;
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      this.myParam = params.myParam;
      if (this.myParam != null) {
        this.editMode = EditMode.APPEND;
      } else {
        this.editMode =  EditMode.NEW;
      }
    });
  }
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code what you wrote works perfectly fine for me. If the `null` is produced as a result of the finding query parameters, it can only happen when the query parameters key ('myParam' in your case) can't be found out.

I have created an example for your help. [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-navigate-with-query-params-ofx7rf)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the example Rafee. Now it works, the problem was in the router config, I think. After I've configured routes I have access to the query params.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make your subscription inside ngOnInit method.
Also I've read in several sources (for example [this](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/angular-constructor-vs-ngoninit-madhumati-hosamani/#targetText=Constructor%20is%20used%20to%20create,finished%20the%20initialization%20of%20component.)) that constructor should be used only for dependencies and variables initialisation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get it from Router
https://angular.io/guide/router

```
constructor(private route: Router) { }

ngOnInit() {
 this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
  console.log(params['myParam']);
   });
 }
```